# Get NPSP Address object fields in a SOQL query

Tags: soql, query, npsp

I wrote the below query and it keeps returning this error:

> "FROM npsp__Address__c)
> ^
> ERROR at Row:11:Column:6
> Didn't understand relationship 'npsp__Address__c' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."

The Address object details are:

API Name:
npsp__Address__c

Custom
True
Singular Label:
Address

Plural Label:
Addresses

The object is part of the NPSP installed package.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

SELECT ID, name, Solicitor__c, Secondary_Solicitor__c, Account_Primary_Solicitors_rollup__c,
(SELECT id, name, phone, npe01__PreferredPhone__c, email,
npe01__Preferred_Email__c  FROM Contacts),
(SELECT id, npsp__Household_Account__c, npsp__Formula_MailingAddress__c,
npsp__MailingCity__c,
npsp__MailingCountry__c,
npsp__MailingState__c,
npsp__Geolocation__c,
npsp__MailingStreet__c,
npsp__MailingPostalCode__c
FROM npsp__Address__c)

FROM Account

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing about the data model here, but I'm assuming the `npsp__Address__c` object is a child of the `Account` object.

When querying child records, you need to use the relationship api name.

At a guess, trying replacing `FROM npsp__Address__c` with `FROM npsp__Address__r`.

If this doesn't work, go to the lookup field in setup and find the relationship name.